# Mystery Seed. Can Anyone Identify It?

Tags: identification, seeds

I've noticed these seeds while gardening this year. They are all over,especially around our small pond -  sometimes singly, sometimes in groups. I'm in Illinois, zone 6, and I've never seen these before.[image]
Posted a pic of a whole seed, and one I opened, with a dime for scale. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You should try to find the tree it belongs to as the tree has more distinct features for more accurate identification.

From what I can see it looks like a Hickory tree nut of some kind, likely in the Carya genus.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I have no hickory trees near my yard. Only Japanese maple. Maybe the squirrels have been busy...there are at least a 50-75 of these nuts in my garden!